# How to theme the table view mode which is showing entities in inline entity form

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am looking for a D8 solution to theme the table view mode.
To start, I would like to remove the main title (the "Legend" tag of the html fieldset).

Note: I know how to use hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter to add/remove columns, I would like to theme what is **outside** the table.

After the remove of the title, I would like to remove the headers of the table ("Title", "Status", "Operations"...)

In fact, if someone have a solution, I would like to get rid of this table view mode.. My final goal is to have a very simple view mode showing only one field and the 2 action button..

Here is the solution I found to remove the header and the title: this is to preprocess fieldset and table hooks

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_fieldset().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_fieldset(&$vars) {
  //Remove the fieldset title/legend for field_myfield
  //as it is a multiple value field, I check only the
  //first part of the id to target field_myfield
  if (strpos($vars['attributes']['id'],'dit-field-myfield')>0){
    unset($vars['legend']);
    unset($vars['legend_span']); 
    $vars['attributes']['style'][]='padding:0';
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_table().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_table(&$vars) {
  //In my use case, I need to target only table that are 
  //generated by ief module. I use the first part of the
  //id to target it
  if (strpos($vars['attributes']['id'], 'ef-entity-table')>0 ) {
    //remove column headers
    unset($vars['header']);
    //adpat layout;
    $vars['attributes']['style'][]='margin:0;border-collapse:separate';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple solution should be to override the table.html.twig template. You can simplify it to your needs in your theme's template directory. Use the core/themes/classy/templates/dataset/table.html.twig file as source to start your theming.

If you don't want to "re-theme" all tables, add "suggestions" for other templates to your tables and create template files accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to add a suggestion with `mytheme_theme_suggestions_table_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)` but it is not called... do you have another idea?

Comment: No. If the API doesn't work as documented it's never a good idea to search for a workaround. Try to find out why your hook is not called. I bet your cache was not cleared!

Comment: `mytheme_theme_suggestions_table_alter` is not called but `mymodule_theme_suggestions_table_alter` is called... Anyway I found another way to solve my problem. I will set your answer as answered and I will add my own solution. Thanks for your help